# Is it possible to copy a dynamically allocated array pointer prior to memory allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays

First off, I apologize if this has been asked before. I can't seem to find the right info.

The following code does not print "300" as I thought it would:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int *array;
  int *arrayCopy = array;

  array = new int[4];

  array[0] = 100;
  array[1] = 200;
  array[2] = 300;
  array[3] = 400;

  std::cout << arrayCopy[2];

  return 0;
}
```

However, it does, if I move the line

```
int *arrayCopy = array;
```

below the line that follows it in the above code. Why is that?

(PS: I know there is a memory leak, and that std::vector is better... I'm just curious).

Comment: BTW, it prints 300 not 200 :)

Comment: There is no memory leak here. At no point is an allocated block "lost" by changing the pointer.

Comment: @paxdiablo I thought that `array` needed to be deleted since memory was allocated using `new`. Is that not so?

Comment: Not in this case, program exit will take care of it. It's still good _form_ to do it but it's not technically necessary.

Comment: @paxdiablo I would still consider this is a memory leak, since there is no `delete`. If this allocation was done in any other function other than `main`, its a memory leak..

Comment: @Marlon, but it _isn't_ done in "any other function than main" hence it's not a leak.

Comment: @paxdiablo: thats a silly definition, because that means memory leaks are impossible on a modern OS.  This is still a memory leak, even if the OS recovers it.

Comment: I'll make this my final comment on the matter since I don't want to clog up the comments. It's only a memory leak if you _lose track_ of allocated memory. In this case you don't - there's no difference between explicitly freeing and exiting here because they both free the memory. It's vastly different from calling a function that allocates memory then loses the pointer value by, for example, not retuning it to the caller - that is indeed a leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of using a reference to a pointer? Here's what happens with your current code:

```
int *array; // Currently points to an undefined (invalid) memory location.
int *arrayCopy = array; // Now this points to the same undefined memory location as array.

array = new int[4]; // Now array points to valid memory, but arrayCopy still points to undefined space.
```

If you did something like this though, it's different:

```
int *array; // Points to undefined
int *&arrayCopy = array; // This is a reference to array. That means if you change array, arrayCopy will also reflect the changes.

array = new int[4]; // Now since array points to valid space, arrayCopy does too.
```

Technically, this isn't entirely true because different things are happening. A reference is essentially the same level of indirection as a pointer, except the compiler does all the dereferencing for you. But what I described is essentially how it works. If you just stick the extra `&` in there, your code will do what you were thinking.

Answer (score 5):

No, when you do `int *arrayCopy = array;` you capture the value of `array` into `arrayCopy` *at that moment of time*, so if you modify (note that initially `array` is pointing to some random location, you make it point to a correct location by doing `new`) the `array` *after* you copied to the `arrayCopy` then those changed will not be reflected back to `arrayCopy`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int *array;                   // array is ???
int *arrayCopy = array;       // copy is ???
array = new int[4];           // array is valid pointer, copy still ???
```

This code snippet does the following:

- creates an `int` pointer of *indeterminate* value (could be anything).
- copies that indeterminate value to the copy.
- changes the value of the original pointer to point to a newly created array.

In other words, the third line "disconnects" the two pointers, leaving the copy still pointing to an indeterminate location.

Dereferencing that pointer copy is undefined behaviour, not something you want to muck about with.

In contrast, if the sequence is changed to (as mentioned in your question):

```
int *array;                   // array is ???
array = new int[4];           // array is valid pointer
int *arrayCopy = array;       // copy is now also the valid pointer
```

then the copy pointer is set to the original *after* the original has been initialised to point to the array. No disconnect occurs, so that `array[2]` is effectively the same as `arrayCopy[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to copy a dynamically allocated array pointer prior to memory allocation?

No.

However, you can do this:

```
int *array;
int *&arrayReference = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *array; // points to some random value
int *arrayCopy = array; // points to the same value

array = new int[4]; // array points to a new value, arrayCopy does not
```

If you want to make a pointer that points to whatever "array" points to at all time, create a double pointer

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c32.htm